# ASP Classic VBscript Parameterized SQL Query?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, ado, parameterized-query

First post but thank you for all the help I've gotten from this site so far.

I'm trying to parameterize an SQL query:

```
query_url = Request.QueryString("ID")

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

cmd.ActiveConnection = Internet_String
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAME FROM OWNER.TABLE WHERE ID = " + "?" + ""

Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, , ,200 , Replace(query_url, "'", "''"))

cmd.Parameters.Append param

Set rs = cmd.Execute()
```

So if I use (no parameters):

```
SELECT NAME FROM OWNER.TABLE WHERE ID = " + Replace(query_url, "'", "''") + ""
```

It works fine, so I know my DB connection and query_url are working. Is something wrong with my SQL statement in the parameterized query? I've tried it so many different ways.

When I run my parameterized query in Dreamweaver the page will not load anytime, just spins infinitely, I'm assuming it's not getting a response back from the DB.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Alright thanks for the help so far, I'm getting closer. The page loads now but the fields are still blank, heres what I've got so far:

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

cmd.ActiveConnection = internet_string    
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAME FROM OWNER.TABLE WHERE ID = @param"

Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@param", , ,200 , query_url)

cmd.Parameters.Append param

response.Write(param)

Set rs = cmd.Execute()
```

Here's how I'm referencing the data:

```
<strong>Name: <%=(rs.Fields.Item("NAME").Value)%></strong>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure about classic asp and vbscript, but in other languages you don't need quotes when you send query parameters.  In any event, use a hard coded value for your paramter as a troubleshooting method.

Comment: Don't substitute apostrophes in the parameter value (i.e., use `cmd.CreateParameter(, , ,200 , query_url`). Since you're using parameters, all the work of escaping special characters is done behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a named placeholder;

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAME FROM OWNER.TABLE WHERE ID = @ID"
```

Then provide its value

```
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@ID", , ,200, Replace(query_url, "'", "''"))
```

FYI you do not need to escape ' in an parameterized query

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I'm receiving a blank page, which is better than timing out, but the name field still isn't populating. The page im working with is a dwt (dreamweaver template file) perhaps this has something to do with why the fields won't populate? Sorry if this just went way outside the scope of my original question.