# NULL Value to a string ASP Classic

Tags: vb.net, string, asp-classic, null

Ok, this one always gets me. I need to insert values to my SQL database. One of column is DateTime and is set to accept Null values.

If the string is empty, it inserts 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000. I understand that SQL converts empty values to 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000. I want it to insert NULL.

I have this code:

```
iDateShipped = request.form("dateshipped")
If iDateShipped = "" Then
    iDateShipped = null
End If
```

That doesn't work either.

My Insert is:

```
sSQL = "INSERT into rma (companyname, contactname, dateshipped)"
sSQL = sSQL & "values('"& replace(strCompany,"'","''") &"','"& replace(strContact,"'","''") &"','"& iDateShipped &"')"
 sSQL = sSQL & "SELECT @@IDENTITY"
 Set rsNewRMA = ConnRMA.Execute(sSQL).NextRecordSet
 rID = rsNewRMA(0)
 rsNewRMA.close
 set rsNewRMA=nothing
```

Any idea?

Comment: How are you updating the database?

Comment: I added my Insert code above.

Comment: What is the type of iDateShipped? Also, what are you using to execute your insert?

Comment: iDateShipped in the SQL database is datetime type. See above for the execute.

Comment: What type is the variable itself (what type is it declared as)? Is it a DataTime as well?

Comment: it's actually a date. But in some cases, the string could be empty.

Comment: @KevenDenen -- looks like `classic asp` so there wouldn't be any datatypes for the local variables.

Comment: @Brasciole -- I'd recommend using a `parameterized query`.  However, if you want your current code to work, you'll need to rebuild your SQL, remove the apos, and check for blank there.  These are different:  `values('null')` vs `values(null)`...

Comment: @sgeddes - As Brasciole mentioned, here is an example of a classic asp parameterized query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790727/asp-classic-vbscript-parameterized-sql-query